# Does Liberty Profile support RMI call

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I am tying to call MDM RMI service with Spring Boot(1.4.2) and Liberty profile beta.When I make a call to RMI service getting **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist**.But same application is working fine in Websphere application server 8.5.

Liberty profile won't support RMI call or am I missing any configuration.I have ebanbled below features in my server.xml.

webProfile-7.0

localConnector-1.0

Comment: Are you trying to make remote EJB calls, or RMI calls? There is a difference, and the Java EE web profile does not include support for remote EJB, but RMI is part Java SE.

Comment: I need to call a MDM server resource which is EJB behind the scene but its exposed as RMI from MDM.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the failure?  As Alasdair suggests, the `webProfile-7.0` does not support remote EJBs, so depending on what you're trying to do, you might try need to enable `ejbRemote-3.2`.

Comment: [err] javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: com/dwl
[err]  at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.ContextNode.getTargetNode(ContextNode.java:126)
[err]  at [internal classes]
[err]  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)

Answer (score 0):

I can able to make remote EJB RMI call with Liberty 16.0.0.3.

Basically we need certain EJB features enabled in Liberty in order to make Remote EJB call.

Download Liberty Full platform from below link.

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/runtimes-wlp-javaee7

Add below features in server.xml.By default this will be part of Full platform Liberty.

```
<feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
    <feature>ejbHome-3.2</feature>
    <feature>ejb-3.2</feature>
```